# Can the graphical layout editor show placeholder images and text?

Tags: android-layout, adt, android-view, placeholder, lorem-ipsum

When adding `TextViews` and `ImageViews` to my layouts that will be populated dynamically at runtime, I often add placeholder text and images so I can preview a realistic layout.  Can the layout editor do this for me without requiring me to explicitly include these strings and images in my application automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like this feature exists, so I created a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35728).

> When adding TextViews and ImageViews to my layouts that will be
>   populated dynamically at runtime, I often add placeholder text and
>   images so I can preview a realistic layout.
>
> Please enable the layout editor do this for me without requiring me to
>   explicitly include these strings and images in my application
>   automatically.  I assume you'd want to have a default image size in
>   the preferences and allow individual ImageViews/texts to override the
>   defaults with something like tools:defaultImageWidth=123px,
>   tools:defaultText="Lorem Ipsum", etc.
>
> tools:numDefaultLoremIpsumTextChars=80 would generate 80 characters of
>   default text.

Answer (score 1):

I followed up Jeff's [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35728) and found out:

> I think this ticket pre-dates the work done under the tools namespace:
>
> http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes
>
> I think that now it is possible to do most everything requested. For
>   setting a placeholder text: tools:text For Images, there is no
>   placeholder image or default size but we can use and android "internal
>   image". Something like:
>
> ```
> <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         tools:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
>         tools:layout_width="100dp"
>         tools:layout_height="100dp"/>
> ```